# CodeIgniter can print only certain views

Tags: php, codeigniter

It's strange but it is happening. My CI app is now rendering a few views, but some of them are found but not rendered, the page remains blank.

I got a controller action that only calls the `load->view` method, but those sassy views keeps not rendering.

The only way I can get the view 'visible' is telling CI to return the view as a data (third parameter as `TRUE`) and dropping an `echo` in the `load->view` instruction.

Anybody with similar situation, now or in the past?

Comment: Can you please post some code for us

Comment: Post your code as well

Comment: I'm just posting a clarfication, guys. Thank you,nevertheless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happens that when you halt the script, no matter how far after from the `view` call, the view gets unrendered.